# How to get handle If application is full screen

Tags: vb6

I can get handle when application is not full screen..  When an application is full screen then I cant..

```
desktophandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, "GOM Player") 
If desktophandle <> 0 Then     
desktophdc = GetWindowDC(desktophandle)
```

for example, when I watch movide with a normal screen its ok. but When I press "alt + enter- fullscreen" its no way.. Maybe the problem is trying to get title name.. when it becomes full screen, it doesnt exist any title?

but i dont know how to get handle of screen ?

its a vb 6.0 code. but you can show a way which can be any programming languge.. it doesnt matter..

Comment: What "handle" are you trying to get? If you pass `NULL` to `GetWindowDC`, you'll get a handle to a device context for the screen. If you want to get a handle to the *desktop window*, then that's considerably more complicated (and useless). If you want a handle to your *form's window*, then you use the `Form.hDC` property.

Comment: I want to get handle of a program which is not mine.. like gom player.. I can get handle.. its not problem.But If screen of gom player is full screen, I cant get handle. Because my codes focuses on title of application. When application hasnt title, i cant get handle.. then I dont know what i will use

Comment: The other application will still have a title when its full screen because it still has a window. You just don't know what the title *is*. Use a program like Spy++ to find out. But this method is inherently fragile precisely because programs *can* change their titles.

Comment: I already used spy++.. But think about game. when game starts there is not exist any title, is it?

Comment: Yes. All windows have titles. And everything in Windows is a window. More to the point: if it's *not* a window, then **it doesn't have a handle**, so there's nothing for you to get.

Answer (score 0):

I just used spy++, setting it to be always on top, to get the details of a full screen video display, using the "Finder Tool" from the "Find Window" tool. You should be able to do the same.

Comment: "Doesnt work" in what way -- what happens? Of course, as Cody Gray said, if it's not a window (which would mean spy++ will see each of the individual windows "behind" the video display), there's no handle to get. This may be possible if the system uses a "hardware" video display enhancement.